# Do I need a bootloader in my existing hard disk to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb, bootloader

The question is aimed at understanding the boot functionality when I try to boot from USB/a pendrive containing an OS. Does it use the bootloader of my existing OS in the HDD when I try to boot from USB?

**Note** : I have already set my boot options to usb.

Any kinds of site links will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit : I am trying to install OS in my hard drive using the bootable USB.

Comment: Nope. In fact, you do not need the hard disk to be present at all, the Ubuntu USB has all it needs to boot from. It is completely irrelevant if there is a hard disk, or if it has a bootloader installed, both are not used when booting from USB.

Comment: If the USB is set properly, it shouldn't need a bootloader on the hard disk, it will just need to be selected on boot. How did you (or how are you planning to) install the OS on the USB?

Comment: @mikewhatever  edited my answer.

Comment: @Wilf I have made my usb bootable using some s/w. While trying to boot the usb, I am getting syslinux error and the cursor is blinking.
After some surfing I found that syslinux searches for the bootloader present in my hard drive. That's why I got this question in my mind.

Comment: s/w? Can you be insanely more specific, or should I try C/y/b/i/m/s?. :~)

Comment: @mikewhatever  OK. I have used unetbootin to make usb bootable.

Comment: I think when I last tried unetbootin it made a annoying mess of the USB - try using [Start-up Disc Creator](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) on Ubuntu, [pendrivelinux](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on windows or [this stuff](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) for mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a bootloader needs to exist just in the device selected by the BIOS.

So as long as the BIOS selects a device containing a bootloader, such bootloader will be able to boot any OS on any device.

If your USB device has a bootloader installed in it, that's enough to be able to boot the OS on the USB device itself (and to boot any other OS present in the USB drive itself and any other OS present in any other device).